Error in SQL syntax with MySQLi PHP, but is valid and runs successfully
This is the PHP code in question:-
$getPts = $mysqli->query("SELECT pts_to_add FROM user_db WHERE user='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($getPts);

$pointsQry = "UPDATE user_db SET points = (points + ".$row['pts_to_add'].") WHERE user ='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$mysqli->query($pointsQry);

Anyways, when executed, this runs perfectly and updates the points, but, when I check the PHP logs, I find this:-

Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
version for the right syntax to use near ') WHERE user ='noob404'' at
line 1

And, when I checked MySQL General log, I see this command was run:-
UPDATE user_db SET points = points +  WHERE user ='noob404'
I tried to change the MySQL code for the username session variable. But, that didn't work. I tried replacing ".$row['pts_to_add']." with 10 and the error disappeared. So, I think it has something to do with how I am declaring it.

Your query does have a ( after the equal sign, and the MySQL General log does not have it ....   So which one is resembling the truth ?

@Luuk I also tried $pointsQry = "UPDATE user_db SET points = points + ".$row['pts_to_add']." WHERE user ='".$_SESSION['username']."'"; $mysqli->query($pointsQry); But it just changes the error to server version for the right syntax to use near WHERE user ='noob404'' at line 1 Is using stmt the recommended approach here?

You can see from the log that the value after the + is missing. Which must mean that $row['pts_to_add'] was empty whe you ran the code. So you need to debug it and find out why.

Is using stmt the recommended approach...yes, absolutely. But if $row['pts_to_add'] is empty, using a prepared statement won't solve that.

when executed, this runs perfectly and updates the points...impossible. You can't have a successfully executed query and an error about that query. So if that's what is really happening, then most likely your query is being executed twice, but one of the times $row['pts_to_add'] has a value, and the other time it does not. Again....more debugging needed. If you require further help from us, post a [mre] of the issue, not just one or two isolated lines of code.

@ADyson Thanks for the reply. That's what confuses me as well. The query executes successfully adding the exact number of points as expected within $row['pts_to_add']. I checked and rechecked multiple times to see if I was missing something. But, each and every time, the addition and the query get executed successfully, but, every time, the query gets executed, regardless of whether there are those  parentheses or not.

@ADyson This is why none of the duplicate questions have helped me. Not sure why I am getting downvoted. But, that's okay, cause pretty sure I did post everything needed and have mentioned about the query executing successfully. As said in the original question, if I replace $row['pts_to_add'] with a direct integer value like 10 and execute it, it not only executes successfully but there are no errors. This, I came to the conclusion that there was some issue with the way I was declaring $row['pts_to_add']. But, no matter what I do, the result is the same.

You are right though. It does need more debugging since this is a weird error. I posted about this thinking someone else might have faced this specific issue before. I will debugging more and make sure I haven't made a silly embarassing mistake in the code. Regardless of any impending embarassment, I will post any updates of I get to fix this or I shall make a reproducible sample. Regardless, thankful to the whole community for helping me and millions of others like me at all times.

@ADyson Your observation was spot on. The script was running twice, due to a rogue Ajax script that was failing to disable the button when/after the PHP script runs. Pardon me for failing to notice this. I thank you for your time. It'd have taken me a few days to even think of the possibility of the code running twice.

@NoobYT no problem. As I said the reason I thought of that is because it's a logical impossibility for the query to have both succeeded and failed in a single execution! And I agree the duplicates don't directly answer your question- although they do contain very good advice which you need to follow in general. I didn't vote for those. Anyway glad you were able to fix it

@ADyson Thank you once again. I will follow the answers in the duplicates and implement them.
